# How to print prompts different than "LABEL" using PrimeFaces' Autocomplete?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I am using Primefaces 3.3, trying to display suggestions in autocomplete that are different than "Label" Is it possible?
My POJO (Projection.class) has fields:

name
String fullTextSearch
String name

I would like to use full text search to look for objects, and name to display suggestions.

my code:

```
 <p:autoComplete id="selectProjection"
                        required="false"
                        minQueryLenenter code heregth="3"
                        forceSelection="true"
                        value="#{view.selectedProjection}"
                        completeMethod="#{view.getFullTextSearches}"
                        var="projection"
                        itemLabel="#{projection.fullTextSearch}"
                        itemValue="#{projection}"
                        converter="standardObjectConverter"
        />
```

view.getFullTextSearches just returns List

converter:

'''

private static final Map entities = new WeakHashMap();

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
    synchronized (entities) {
        if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            entities.put(entity, uuid);
            return uuid;
        } else {
            return entities.get(entity);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
    for (Entry<Object, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
```

'''

thanks in advance

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by _display suggestions in autocomplete that are different than "Label"_  You have an `itemLabel` in your code. Doesn't that get displayed? And you are aware you are asking about an 8 year old version? I'd say time to upgrade (long over due)

Comment: I am aware of that. What can I say? Old monster to maintain.

What I mean is suggestions should be different than the field that I browse.
Lets say I want to look for a name Mark.
full tex search is : "name" + "surname" + "id" + "shoe number" +"something else"
I want my autocomplete to show me only name and surname when i type "Mark" instead of the whole fullTextSearch field value, But when i type "8.5" , Mark should also appear

Comment: You describe what you want but do not answer what your `itemLabel` does. Does it display what you assign? Does it not work at all? Why don't you assign what you want to see?